# how to hide files or content in file manager in both android ios

Tags: file, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, information-hiding

Hi i am developing a reader mobile application in xamarin.forms. once user downloading the book it will download zip file. so when user click on read that time i am unzipping and showing content. after reading completion again i am zipping. but when reader is opened that time all files ale available in file manager. i want to hide or provide security to the files. i need to restrict access files from the file manager. how can i provide security to the content? please suggest me.. thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you could try to restrict  the file type , only show the file whose type is `zip` .

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT hi thanks for the response. And do you have any idea to restrict.

Comment: Which file manager did you use ? You could check the plugin file picker :https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows ,it supports ios and android , you can specify file types when pick files :https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows#methods